# How to see all queries via pgBadger

Tags: postgresql

The excellent pgBadger has an interface to reviewing specific queries - the slowest, by host, by user etc.

Is it possible to see all queries processed, perhaps in a given timeframe.

If not available out of the box, does anyone have pointers on how to modify the application to do this?

http://dalibo.github.io/pgbadger/